# Issues getting correct data from gremlin server

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server, graphson

I am having a series of nonsensical issues that are driving me nuts. There are a couple of things I am trying to accomplish:

1. I am trying to set up my gremlin server to "load" a certain `json` file that is in `graphson` format, and getting really weird issues there that I will go into details about.
2. I am trying to run a simple ajax call to query that data, but - not only am I not able to get the data I want (which might make sense since gremlin refuses to load it), I seem to be getting some data that I have *no idea* where it comes from.
3. I am trying to figure out how to test the gremlin server on my terminal, but I cannot run a query because `./gremlin-server.sh status` returns `Server not running` even though it is 100% running and my ajax call can see that.

## Gremlin not loading file

To start up, I am running Gremlin v.3.4.3 and that can be found [here](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/tinkerpop/3.4.3/apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-server-3.4.3-bin.zip). The command I use to run gremlin is

`bin/gremlin-server.sh data/gremlin-server-rest-modern.yaml`

Te yaml file comes with the Gremlin Server downloads, the contents of which are:

```
#...license stuff...

host: localhost
port: 8182
scriptEvaluationTimeout: 30000
channelizer: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.channel.HttpChannelizer
graphs: {
  graph: conf/tinkergraph-empty.properties}
scriptEngines: {
  gremlin-groovy: {
    plugins: { org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.jsr223.GremlinServerGremlinPlugin: {},
               org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.jsr223.TinkerGraphGremlinPlugin: {},
               org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.ImportGremlinPlugin: {classImports: [java.lang.Math], methodImports: [java.lang.Math#*]},
               org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.ScriptFileGremlinPlugin: {files: [scripts/generate-modern.groovy]}}}}
serializers:
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerIoRegistryV3d0] }}         # application/json
metrics: {
  slf4jReporter: {enabled: true, interval: 180000}}
strictTransactionManagement: false
maxInitialLineLength: 4096
maxHeaderSize: 8192
maxChunkSize: 8192
maxContentLength: 65536
maxAccumulationBufferComponents: 1024
resultIterationBatchSize: 64
```

Now, as I understand it, the important thing to note is the component `graph` that leads to a `properties` file. The properties file I am loading is `tinkergraph-empty.properties`, the contents of which are:

```
gremlin.graph=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerGraph
gremlin.tinkergraph.vertexIdManager=LONG
```

The file name, `tinkergraph-empty`, alludes to something important: the gremlin server will not load a graph. Cool - when I start the gremlin server, it loads up normally with results that I can expect:

```
[INFO] GremlinServer - Configuring Gremlin Server from ./conf/gremlin-server-rest-modern.yaml
[INFO] MetricManager - Configured Metrics Slf4jReporter configured with interval=180000ms and loggerName=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.Settings$Slf4jReporterMetrics
[INFO] DefaultGraphManager - Graph [graph] was successfully configured via [conf/tinkergraph-empty.properties].
[INFO] ServerGremlinExecutor - Initialized Gremlin thread pool.  Threads in pool named with pattern gremlin-*
[INFO] ServerGremlinExecutor - Initialized GremlinExecutor and preparing GremlinScriptEngines instances.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1 (file:/Users/<user>/apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-server-3.4.3/lib/groovy-2.5.7-indy.jar) to constructor java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup(java.lang.Class,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[INFO] ServerGremlinExecutor - Initialized gremlin-groovy GremlinScriptEngine and registered metrics
[INFO] ServerGremlinExecutor - A GraphTraversalSource is now bound to [g] with graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
[INFO] OpLoader - Adding the standard OpProcessor.
[INFO] OpLoader - Adding the session OpProcessor.
[INFO] OpLoader - Adding the traversal OpProcessor.
[INFO] TraversalOpProcessor - Initialized cache for TraversalOpProcessor with size 1000 and expiration time of 600000 ms
[INFO] GremlinServer - Executing start up LifeCycleHook
[INFO] Logger$info - Loading 'modern' graph data.
[INFO] AbstractChannelizer - Configured application/vnd.gremlin-v3.0+json with org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0
[INFO] AbstractChannelizer - Configured application/json with org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0
[INFO] GremlinServer$1 - Gremlin Server configured with worker thread pool of 1, gremlin pool of 8 and boss thread pool of 1.
[INFO] GremlinServer$1 - Channel started at port 8182.
```

This line, specifically, is promising: `[INFO] ServerGremlinExecutor - A GraphTraversalSource is now bound to [g] with graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]`

The graph it "loads" (I am assuming it must initialize a graph) has zero vertices and edges.

When I run my ajax call, which as I promised, I will get into later, I successfully POST to the server. It's up and running. All is well.

However...

When I change the `tinkerpop-empty.properties` folder to load a graph, things get really weird. I am going to change it as such:

```
gremlin.graph=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerGraph
gremlin.tinkergraph.vertexIdManager=LONG
gremlin.tinkergraph.graphLocation=data/tinkerpop-crew.json
gremlin.tinkergraph.graphFormat=graphson
```

I now loaded up a data folder called `tinkerpop-crew.json` and added a `graphFormat: graphson`. This should be correct. json file can be found [here](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/master/data/tinkerpop-crew.json), and the properties file follows the format of this [file](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/master/gremlin-server/conf/tinkergraph-credentials.properties).

Now, when I run this, I get a much different result:

```
[INFO] GremlinServer - Configuring Gremlin Server from ./conf/gremlin-server-rest-modern.yaml
[INFO] MetricManager - Configured Metrics Slf4jReporter configured with interval=180000ms and loggerName=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.Settings$Slf4jReporterMetrics
[INFO] DefaultGraphManager - Graph [graph] was successfully configured via [conf/tinkergraph-empty.properties].
[INFO] ServerGremlinExecutor - Initialized Gremlin thread pool.  Threads in pool named with pattern gremlin-*
[INFO] ServerGremlinExecutor - Initialized GremlinExecutor and preparing GremlinScriptEngines instances.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1 (file:/Users/xbbn1xn/apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-server-3.4.3/lib/groovy-2.5.7-indy.jar) to constructor java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup(java.lang.Class,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[INFO] ServerGremlinExecutor - Initialized gremlin-groovy GremlinScriptEngine and registered metrics
[INFO] ServerGremlinExecutor - A GraphTraversalSource is now bound to [g] with graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:14], standard]
[INFO] OpLoader - Adding the standard OpProcessor.
[INFO] OpLoader - Adding the session OpProcessor.
[INFO] OpLoader - Adding the traversal OpProcessor.
[INFO] TraversalOpProcessor - Initialized cache for TraversalOpProcessor with size 1000 and expiration time of 600000 ms
[INFO] GremlinServer - Executing start up LifeCycleHook
[INFO] Logger$info - Loading 'modern' graph data.
[ERROR] GremlinServer - Gremlin Server Error
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Vertex with id already exists: 1
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Graph$Exceptions.vertexWithIdAlreadyExists(Graph.java:1196)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerGraph.addVertex(TinkerGraph.java:167)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerFactory.generateModern(TinkerFactory.java:90)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerFactory$generateModern.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:127)
    at Script1$_run_closure1.doCall(Script1.groovy:28)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:263)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ConvertedMap.invokeCustom(ConvertedMap.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ConversionHandler.invoke(ConversionHandler.java:122)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.onStartUp(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.lambda$start$1(GremlinServer.java:154)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.start(GremlinServer.java:151)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.main(GremlinServer.java:346)
[ERROR] GremlinServer - Gremlin Server was unable to start and will now begin shutdown: Vertex with id already exists: 1
[INFO] GremlinServer - Shutting down OpProcessor[]
[INFO] GremlinServer - Shutting down OpProcessor[session]
[INFO] GremlinServer - Shutting down OpProcessor[traversal]
[INFO] GremlinServer - Shutting down thread pools.
[INFO] GremlinServer - Executing shutdown LifeCycleHook
[INFO] GremlinServer - Closed Graph instance [graph]
[INFO] GremlinServer - Gremlin Server - shutdown complete
```

Huh? Vertex already exists? That's impossible. I have never even *run* this file, why would there even be any memory of it? As far as gremlin should be concerned, I have never even loaded a graph. Maybe it initiates a graph though and forgets to delete it from memory or something, right?

Well, let's make our own file and initialize just one Vertex and of some weird prime number and no edges. Let's call it `tinkerpop-crew2.json`:

`{"id":{"@type":"g:Int64","@value":47284629},"label":"person"}`.

Might not be prime. Whatever. Okay, awesome, that worked!

```
[INFO] GremlinServer - Configuring Gremlin Server from ./conf/gremlin-server-rest-modern.yaml
[INFO] MetricManager - Configured Metrics Slf4jReporter configured with interval=180000ms and loggerName=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.Settings$Slf4jReporterMetrics
[INFO] DefaultGraphManager - Graph [graph] was successfully configured via [conf/tinkergraph-empty.properties].
[INFO] ServerGremlinExecutor - Initialized Gremlin thread pool.  Threads in pool named with pattern gremlin-*
[INFO] ServerGremlinExecutor - Initialized GremlinExecutor and preparing GremlinScriptEngines instances.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1 (file:/Users/xbbn1xn/apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-server-3.4.3/lib/groovy-2.5.7-indy.jar) to constructor java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup(java.lang.Class,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[INFO] ServerGremlinExecutor - Initialized gremlin-groovy GremlinScriptEngine and registered metrics
[INFO] ServerGremlinExecutor - A GraphTraversalSource is now bound to [g] with graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:1 edges:0], standard]
[INFO] OpLoader - Adding the standard OpProcessor.
[INFO] OpLoader - Adding the session OpProcessor.
[INFO] OpLoader - Adding the traversal OpProcessor.
[INFO] TraversalOpProcessor - Initialized cache for TraversalOpProcessor with size 1000 and expiration time of 600000 ms
[INFO] GremlinServer - Executing start up LifeCycleHook
[INFO] Logger$info - Loading 'modern' graph data.
[INFO] AbstractChannelizer - Configured application/vnd.gremlin-v3.0+json with org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0
[INFO] AbstractChannelizer - Configured application/json with org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0
[INFO] GremlinServer$1 - Gremlin Server configured with worker thread pool of 1, gremlin pool of 8 and boss thread pool of 1.
[INFO] GremlinServer$1 - Channel started at port 8182.
```

Pay attention here: `[INFO] ServerGremlinExecutor - A GraphTraversalSource is now bound to [g] with graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:1 edges:0], standard]`. One vertice.

What happens when we th server configured to use this file again?

```
[INFO] GremlinServer - Configuring Gremlin Server from ./conf/gremlin-server-rest-modern.yaml
[INFO] MetricManager - Configured Metrics Slf4jReporter configured with interval=180000ms and loggerName=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.Settings$Slf4jReporterMetrics
[INFO] DefaultGraphManager - Graph [graph] was successfully configured via [conf/tinkergraph-empty.properties].
[INFO] ServerGremlinExecutor - Initialized Gremlin thread pool.  Threads in pool named with pattern gremlin-*
[INFO] ServerGremlinExecutor - Initialized GremlinExecutor and preparing GremlinScriptEngines instances.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1 (file:/Users/xbbn1xn/apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-server-3.4.3/lib/groovy-2.5.7-indy.jar) to constructor java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup(java.lang.Class,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[INFO] ServerGremlinExecutor - Initialized gremlin-groovy GremlinScriptEngine and registered metrics
[INFO] ServerGremlinExecutor - A GraphTraversalSource is now bound to [g] with graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:7 edges:6], standard]
[INFO] OpLoader - Adding the standard OpProcessor.
[INFO] OpLoader - Adding the session OpProcessor.
[INFO] OpLoader - Adding the traversal OpProcessor.
[INFO] TraversalOpProcessor - Initialized cache for TraversalOpProcessor with size 1000 and expiration time of 600000 ms
[INFO] GremlinServer - Executing start up LifeCycleHook
[INFO] Logger$info - Loading 'modern' graph data.
[ERROR] GremlinServer - Gremlin Server Error
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Vertex with id already exists: 1
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Graph$Exceptions.vertexWithIdAlreadyExists(Graph.java:1196)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerGraph.addVertex(TinkerGraph.java:167)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerFactory.generateModern(TinkerFactory.java:90)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerFactory$generateModern.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:127)
    at Script1$_run_closure1.doCall(Script1.groovy:28)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:263)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ConvertedMap.invokeCustom(ConvertedMap.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ConversionHandler.invoke(ConversionHandler.java:122)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.onStartUp(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.lambda$start$1(GremlinServer.java:154)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.start(GremlinServer.java:151)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.main(GremlinServer.java:346)
[ERROR] GremlinServer - Gremlin Server was unable to start and will now begin shutdown: Vertex with id already exists: 1
[INFO] GremlinServer - Shutting down OpProcessor[]
[INFO] GremlinServer - Shutting down OpProcessor[session]
[INFO] GremlinServer - Shutting down OpProcessor[traversal]
[INFO] GremlinServer - Shutting down thread pools.
[INFO] GremlinServer - Executing shutdown LifeCycleHook
[INFO] GremlinServer - Closed Graph instance [graph]
[INFO] GremlinServer - Gremlin Server - shutdown complete
```

Same error as before. What the hell is going on here? There are also two things that catch my eye:

1. `ERROR] GremlinServer - Gremlin Server Error
   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Vertex with id already exists: 1`. Is it saying that only one vertex exists, or the vertex with ID '1' exists? Because none of my vertices have an ID of one. That is, until...
2. You notice that this is not even loading my file! `[INFO] ServerGremlinExecutor - A GraphTraversalSource is now bound to [g] with graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:7 edges:6], standard]`. My file does not have 7 vertices and 6 edges. It has 1 vertex and 0 edges. This actually looks suspiciously like it's loading the original `tinkerpop-crew.json` file, or something similar, even though when we originally loaded it, the INFO message said: `[INFO] ServerGremlinExecutor - A GraphTraversalSource is now bound to [g] with graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:14], standard]`.

Okay, so I have no idea what is going on here.

## Running my ajax query to see what is happening

I have a really, really simple query that I run and post using an AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            accept: "application/json",
            url: url // http://localhost:8182,
            timeout: timeout // I have it set to 3500,
            data: JSON.stringify({"gremlin" : q}),
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                            var retrvData = data.result.data;
                            console.log(retrvData)
}
```

Okay, so a couple of important things. The `q` variable is a query that I send to the Gremlin server to return some data, and it looks like this:

`q = 'nodes = g.V().limit(15).toList();edges = g.V(nodes).aggregate('node').outE().as('edge').inV().where(within('node')).select('edge').toList();[nodes,edges]'`

This query should essentially return a list of nodes and edges. Now, there are three cases I want to go over:

#### tinkerpop-empty.properties (actually empty):

The first case is using the unaltered tinkerpop-empty.properties file. Remember, when I loaded that, I got output that said:

`[INFO] ServerGremlinExecutor - A GraphTraversalSource is now bound to [g] with graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]`

That means there should be no information in the tinkergraph. I should receive an empty list. However, when I run my call, I get this:

```
value: Array(2)
0: Array(7)
0: {id: 1, label: "person", type: "vertex"}
1: {id: 2, label: "person", type: "vertex"}
2: {id: 3, label: "software", type: "vertex"}
3: {id: 47284629, label: "person", type: "vertex"}
4: {id: 4, label: "person", type: "vertex"}
5: {id: 5, label: "software", type: "vertex"}
6: {id: 6, label: "person", type: "vertex"}
length: 7
__proto__: Array(0)
1: Array(6)
0: {id: 9, label: "created", inVLabel: "software", outVLabel: "person", inV: 3, …}
1: {id: 7, label: "knows", inVLabel: "person", outVLabel: "person", inV: 2, …}
2: {id: 8, label: "knows", inVLabel: "person", outVLabel: "person", inV: 4, …}
3: {id: 10, label: "created", inVLabel: "software", outVLabel: "person", inV: 5, …}
4: {id: 11, label: "created", inVLabel: "software", outVLabel: "person", inV: 3, …}
5: {id: 12, label: "created", inVLabel: "software", outVLabel: "person", inV: 3, …}
length: 6
```

This is the output in the developer console (from console.log(retrvData)). There are all kinds of data. And look, the length of the nodes is 7, and the edges is 6. Sound familiar? Why is gremlin loading this data? Why is it sending it to my ajax query?

#### tinkergraph-empty.properties (modified to use tinkerpop-crew.json)

Okay, whatever. Let's run the next `properties` file. Remember, we are using `tinkerpop-crew.json` now with the graphFormat set to graphson.

I get the same error that I got before, of course, which is `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Vertex with id already exists: 1`. My server also shuts down:

```
[ERROR] GremlinServer - Gremlin Server was unable to start and will now begin shutdown: Vertex with id already exists: 1
[INFO] GremlinServer - Shutting down OpProcessor[]
[INFO] GremlinServer - Shutting down OpProcessor[session]
[INFO] GremlinServer - Shutting down OpProcessor[traversal]
[INFO] GremlinServer - Shutting down thread pools.
[INFO] GremlinServer - Executing shutdown LifeCycleHook
[INFO] GremlinServer - Closed Graph instance [graph]
[INFO] GremlinServer - Gremlin Server - shutdown complete
```

Let's go to my AJAX query and see what we get.

Nothing, of course. My gremlin server crashed. It seems like it could be loading the correct file, since the INFO log says `A GraphTraversalSource is now bound to [g] with graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:14], standard]`. I haven't verified that this is correct... it's not that easy.

#### tinkerpop-empty.properties loading tinkerpop-crew2.json

The first time we ran `tinkerpop-crew2.json`, things went well. We changed the ID to some weird number and didn't get an exception thrown. Also, the graph seemed to load the correct stuff. Let's run it again now, and change the ID to `4724729456382`.

Okay, wow, I am typing this as I go, and look what I just found:

```
{"id":{"@type":"g:Int64","@value":1},"label":"person","outE":{"created":[{"id":{"@type":"g:Int32","@value":9},"inV":{"@type":"g:Int64","@value":3},"properties":{"weight":{"@type":"g:Double","@value":0.4}}}],"knows":[{"id":{"@type":"g:Int32","@value":7},"inV":{"@type":"g:Int64","@value":2},"properties":{"weight":{"@type":"g:Double","@value":0.5}}},{"id":{"@type":"g:Int32","@value":8},"inV":{"@type":"g:Int64","@value":4},"properties":{"weight":{"@type":"g:Double","@value":1.0}}}]},"properties":{"name":[{"id":{"@type":"g:Int64","@value":0},"value":"marko"}],"age":[{"id":{"@type":"g:Int64","@value":2},"value":{"@type":"g:Int32","@value":29}}]}}
{"id":{"@type":"g:Int64","@value":2},"label":"person","inE":{"knows":[{"id":{"@type":"g:Int32","@value":7},"outV":{"@type":"g:Int64","@value":1},"properties":{"weight":{"@type":"g:Double","@value":0.5}}}]},"properties":{"name":[{"id":{"@type":"g:Int64","@value":3},"value":"vadas"}],"age":[{"id":{"@type":"g:Int64","@value":4},"value":{"@type":"g:Int32","@value":27}}]}}
{"id":{"@type":"g:Int64","@value":3},"label":"software","inE":{"created":[{"id":{"@type":"g:Int32","@value":9},"outV":{"@type":"g:Int64","@value":1},"properties":{"weight":{"@type":"g:Double","@value":0.4}}},{"id":{"@type":"g:Int32","@value":11},"outV":{"@type":"g:Int64","@value":4},"properties":{"weight":{"@type":"g:Double","@value":0.4}}},{"id":{"@type":"g:Int32","@value":12},"outV":{"@type":"g:Int64","@value":6},"properties":{"weight":{"@type":"g:Double","@value":0.2}}}]},"properties":{"name":[{"id":{"@type":"g:Int64","@value":5},"value":"lop"}],"lang":[{"id":{"@type":"g:Int64","@value":6},"value":"java"}]}}
{"id":{"@type":"g:Int64","@value":4},"label":"person","inE":{"knows":[{"id":{"@type":"g:Int32","@value":8},"outV":{"@type":"g:Int64","@value":1},"properties":{"weight":{"@type":"g:Double","@value":1.0}}}]},"outE":{"created":[{"id":{"@type":"g:Int32","@value":10},"inV":{"@type":"g:Int64","@value":5},"properties":{"weight":{"@type":"g:Double","@value":1.0}}},{"id":{"@type":"g:Int32","@value":11},"inV":{"@type":"g:Int64","@value":3},"properties":{"weight":{"@type":"g:Double","@value":0.4}}}]},"properties":{"name":[{"id":{"@type":"g:Int64","@value":7},"value":"josh"}],"age":[{"id":{"@type":"g:Int64","@value":8},"value":{"@type":"g:Int32","@value":32}}]}}
{"id":{"@type":"g:Int64","@value":5},"label":"software","inE":{"created":[{"id":{"@type":"g:Int32","@value":10},"outV":{"@type":"g:Int64","@value":4},"properties":{"weight":{"@type":"g:Double","@value":1.0}}}]},"properties":{"name":[{"id":{"@type":"g:Int64","@value":9},"value":"ripple"}],"lang":[{"id":{"@type":"g:Int64","@value":10},"value":"java"}]}}
{"id":{"@type":"g:Int64","@value":6},"label":"person","outE":{"created":[{"id":{"@type":"g:Int32","@value":12},"inV":{"@type":"g:Int64","@value":3},"properties":{"weight":{"@type":"g:Double","@value":0.2}}}]},"properties":{"name":[{"id":{"@type":"g:Int64","@value":11},"value":"peter"}],"age":[{"id":{"@type":"g:Int64","@value":12},"value":{"@type":"g:Int32","@value":35}}]}}
{"id":{"@type":"g:Int64","@value":47284629},"label":"person"}
```

This is now the contents of my `tinkerpop-crew2.json`! What is going on here? Why did the gremlin-server dump information to that file? If you see the last line, it has what was the original content of the file:

`{"id":{"@type":"g:Int64","@value":47284629},"label":"person"}`

Okay, really, @tinkerpop, what the hell?

I guess it now makes sense why when I ran the file the second time, it threw that error again and said that the vertex with id 1 was already existing!

Hilariously, I digress! Let us delete the unoriginal portion of that file and just run it with:

`{"id":{"@type":"g:Int64","@value":47284629},"label":"person"}`

Okay, that ran fine with the correct INFO that I should be expecting: `[INFO] ServerGremlinExecutor - A GraphTraversalSource is now bound to [g] with graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:1 edges:0], standard]`.

Now, let's run that AJAX call...

Gahh!! Same thing!!

```
value: Array(2)
0: Array(7)
0: {id: 1, label: "person", type: "vertex"}
1: {id: 2, label: "person", type: "vertex"}
2: {id: 3, label: "software", type: "vertex"}
3: {id: 47284629, label: "person", type: "vertex"}
4: {id: 4, label: "person", type: "vertex"}
5: {id: 5, label: "software", type: "vertex"}
6: {id: 6, label: "person", type: "vertex"}
length: 7
__proto__: Array(0)
1: Array(6)
0: {id: 9, label: "created", inVLabel: "software", outVLabel: "person", inV: 3, …}
1: {id: 7, label: "knows", inVLabel: "person", outVLabel: "person", inV: 2, …}
2: {id: 8, label: "knows", inVLabel: "person", outVLabel: "person", inV: 4, …}
3: {id: 10, label: "created", inVLabel: "software", outVLabel: "person", inV: 5, …}
4: {id: 11, label: "created", inVLabel: "software", outVLabel: "person", inV: 3, …}
5: {id: 12, label: "created", inVLabel: "software", outVLabel: "person", inV: 3, …}
length: 6
```

Notice how the nodes list is of length 7 and the edges is of lenth 6! Assuming it was loading something, for example, *and* appending my file, it should be node length 8 and edge length 7! What's going on here?

## Accepted Answer

The solution was to go into `scripts/generate-modern.groovy` and comment out these lines:

```
globals << [hook : [
  onStartUp: { ctx ->
    ctx.logger.info("Loading 'modern' graph data.")
      org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerFactory.generateModern(graph)
  }
] as LifeCycleHook]
```

Comment: This is certainly very weird... maybe Stephen Malette can help you on the Google Forms.

Comment: @user3026388 Can't post there, keep getting an err msg "An error occurred while communicating with the server." It's almost prophetic.

Comment: Interesting, I am getting the same error. Something must be up, wait some time I guess.

Comment: if you're referring to google groups - there's definitely something weird going on. people are literally submitting dozens of identical posts (over last three days) and they are flooding moderation. i guess i now know that folks don't realize they are actually going through so they keep resubmitting. i'm sorta dealing with your question here, do you still want it to go through to the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think things start to go wrong for you here:

> When I change the tinkerpop-empty.properties folder to load a graph, things get really weird. I am going to change it as such:
>
> gremlin.graph=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerGraph
>   gremlin.tinkergraph.vertexIdManager=LONG
>   gremlin.tinkergraph.graphLocation=data/tinkerpop-crew.json
>   gremlin.tinkergraph.graphFormat=graphson

You get the error that you do because you're missing the fact that the Gremlin Server initialization script is running - this line in your yaml:

https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/3.4.3/gremlin-server/conf/gremlin-server-rest-modern.yaml

so that is trying to load the "modern" graph into a graph that you're trying to specify as the "crew" graph (or the other way around, i can't remember which loads first but I think I got that right). The solution is to either:

1. Comment out the lines that load the "modern" graph in your `scripts/generate-modern.groovy` and keep your properties file as is OR
2. Change the `scripts/generate-modern.groovy` init script to just load the "crew" data and leave the properties file unchanged to have an empty graph.

You have a long list of other odds/ends that looked weird, but I wonder how much of it stems from missing the init file and what it's doing to you "behind your back". Does this knowledge help solve all of your issues? If not, let me know what is still amiss and I can try to help resolve it.

Comment: Hey Stephen, I tried the first suggestion, but that gave me an error when I ran the AJAX query (appeared on the gremlin console): `[WARN] HttpGremlinEndpointHandler - Invalid request - responding with 500 Internal Server Error and No such property: g for class: Script2
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: g for class: Script2]`.

Could you let me know how I can do your second suggestion?  I can't edit my post because I have reached the character limit... we can also take this to a chat and leave an update later with what worked, if you think that's a good idea.

Comment: Wait! Aha! The first suggestion worked! I was doing something wrong. Thanks a lot man... I knew it was something simple. I looked at that script and tried to see what that function did exactly, but couldn't find it quick enough in the binaries, so I gave up. Should have continued... anyways, thanks

Comment: excellent. always nice when the problem is solved just by some configuration tweaking

Comment: https://media1.tenor.com/images/07feba4572471b21fd4258b6af83c9c4/tenor.gif?itemid=4158682

Comment: Is there a gremlin library I can use with javascript that accomplishes the same thing the gremlin server does, but I can utilize it like a library, not like an API?

Comment: Basically, I don't have to make any server connections. Something I can use within my own directory

Comment: Gremlin-Javascript and other Gremlin Language Variants (GLVs) are meant to allow you to write Gremlin in your native programming language such that the traversal you write can be transmitted for execution at a remote source (e.g Gremlin Server, DataStax Graph, Amazon Neptune, etc). By themselves GLVs do not have graph processing engines or even graph data structures on which to process. This in contrast to Java where we have a full TinkerPop virtual machine (VM) for doing such things. So, GLVs are just the Gremlin language interface to a TinkerPop VM and therefore need that VM to execute.

Comment: It would be cool if we had a native Javascript TinkerPop VM but it would basically mean porting the full Java library to Javascript and supporting all which that entails. Not a small effort obviously. Given that the most popular Gremlin providers are remote sources anyway (DataStax Graph, Neptune, CosmosDB, and so on) how you interact with Gremlin through a GLV is pretty much how you interact with Java at this point. The missing use case is the small in-memory graph situations I guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199931/discussion-between-john-lexus-and-stephen-mallette).